# Type converter in WPF Custom Control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating a custom control in WPF and would like to have my converters in a separate resource dictionary to make things cleaner.  I have a `ControlStyling.xaml` resource dictionary for the styling of my controls

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DialIndicatorControl">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyDialIndicator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyDialIndicator}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <Ellipse Width="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizeRadius}"                                           

                    </Ellipse>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

A `Converters.xaml` resource dictionary where I would like to keep my converteres

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DialIndicatorControl">

<local:RadiusDiameterConverter x:Key="RadiusConvert"/>
```

And the Themes/Generic.xaml where I am pointing to both of these dictionaries.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DialIndicatorControl">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>       
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/DialIndicatorControl;component/Themes/Generic/Converters.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/DialIndicatorControl;component/Themes/Generic/ControlStyling.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

The problem I am having is when I place my converters in a separate resource dictionary my `ControlStyling.xaml` dictionary doesn't have a reference to the converters (which seems obvious now that I think about it).  I thought that I would be able to use these converters since I merged both dictionaries in my `Themes/Generic.xaml` dictionary but that didn't work.   Is there a good way to have all my converters in a separate dictionary and still be able to reference them in my `ControlStyling.xaml` for this custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the converter resource dictionary from the styling dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>       
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/DialIndicatorControl;component/Themes/Generic/Converters.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```